# A variable array into separate items

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, variables, foreach

I'm not sure where I am going wrong with this code.  I'm simply trying to output an array from a variable into it's separate items.

For example:

```
$current_endMaps = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_tsb_postmeta_end_maps", true);
```

Will give me the following output...

```
["http://localhost/lmn-beta/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/image1.png","http://localhost/lmn-beta/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/image2.png"]
```

But I am trying to output this as follows...

```
http://localhost/lmn-beta/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/image1.png
http://localhost/lmn-beta/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/image2.png
```

Here is what I have so far... but this is only outputting this

```
[
```

Here is the code I am using..

```
$current_endMaps = get_post_meta($post->ID, "_tsb_postmeta_end_maps", true);
$arrlength = count($current_endMaps);
for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
    echo $current_endMaps[$x];
    echo "<br>";
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is it not working? There is a simpler way to loop an array in PHP, but this should nevertheless be working.

Comment: Whats the easier way?  I'm assuming that something in wordpress is just messing up the output.

Comment: The `[` output is suspicious. View the page source of the resultant output. Do you see additional stuff in there, like broken, non-rendered HTML?  Instead of `echo $current_endMaps[$x]` debug with `var_dump($current_endMals[$x]`.

Comment: Also, incrementing `for ()` loops are rarely used in PHP when iterating an array. This shouldn't affect your output, but instead I'd recommend `foreach($current_endMaps as $current_endMap) {...}` and access inside simply as `echo $current_endMap`

Comment: I don't know.  Something must be wrong because I've done this many times before but the output is either the same or showing errors.

Comment: According to the [WordPress docs](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/), you are getting exactly what you asked for.

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to supply `false` as the third argument to get_post_meta() to get an array

see https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_meta/

> $single (bool) (Optional) Whether to return a single value. Default value: false

Answer (score 0):

Found out what I was doing wrong...

Just added json_decode to the initial array...

```
$current_endMaps = json_decode(get_post_meta( $post->ID, "_tsb_postmeta_end_maps", true ));
$arrlength = count($current_endMaps);
for($x = 0; $x < $arrlength; $x++) {
    echo "<img src='".$current_endMaps[$x]."' width='100%'>";
}
```

Then finished the echo output as an image.  Works now.